# array.push(object) not pushed at the end of the loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var temparray1 = [[1,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]];
var final = [];
var obj = {};
for(var temp in temparray1){
    for(var test in temparray1[temp]){
        obj.b = temparray1[temp][0];
        obj.c = temparray1[temp][1];
        obj.d = temparray1[temp][2];
    }
    console.log(obj);
    final.push(obj);
}
```

**current output**

```
[{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }
{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }
{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }]
```

**expected Out put**:

```
[{ b: 1, c: 3, d: 4 }
{ b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 }
{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }]
```

i am running my javascript in `node.js -v 8.1.x` server

in the console at the end of the for loop it prints the required out put but not in the array push

Comment: Never use `for ..in` loops to iterate over arrays, and `obj` isn't defined in your code ?

Comment: yes obj = {} already declared but may i know why for ..in is not possible it is the normal iteration i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var temparray = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]];
const final = temparray.map(a => ({ b: a[0], c: a[1], d: a[2] }));

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you set obj outside the for loop, therefore the props are overwritten and you push the same object multiple times into the array. Simply move the obj declaration into the loop. And you probably just need the outer loop.

Btw much shorter:

```
let final = temparray1.map(
 ([b,c,d]) => ({b,c,d})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you wanted

```
var temparray1 = [[1,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]];
var final = [];
for(var temp in temparray1){
   var obj = {};
   obj['b'] = temparray1[temp][0];
   obj['c'] = temparray1[temp][1];
   obj['d'] = temparray1[temp][2];
   final.push(obj);
}
console.log(final);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what errors are you getting ? I can send you a live example for it, if you want it

Comment: the above code push only the last occurene of array [{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }
{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }
{ b: 8, c: 9, d: 10 }]  @zenwraight  array.map function is the correct apporach

Comment: I have posted the link of my live example above @muthukumar, please run it and see for yourself

Comment: Thank you @zenwraight it worked for me i have changed your array to objects really nice and great ` var obj = {};`

Comment: What issue you are facing @Jonasw, it's is one the perfect answer for the above question

Comment: @Jonasw ya I agree making use of one more array is unnecessary but I thought it will better for him to understand where was he making the mistake, because the question description and heading doesn't ask use to optimize his technique or anything similar

Comment: i mostly use array.map() approach for this scenario that is efficient i think @Jonasw but the above answer is not the wrong answer

Comment: @Jonasw made the update, thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return an object with the wanted properties.

```js
var array = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]],
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return { b: a[0], c: a[1], d: a[2] };
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With ES6, you could map the inner arrays as well with an array for the keys with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var array = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]],
    keys = ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    result = array.map(a => Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```